# using pandas to count how often an item appears in a seperate dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, the first being like so, with the ID being a unique value.

```
 ID     Etc     Etc2
 001    foo     bar
 002    foo2    bar2
 003    foo3    bar3
```

The second being like this where ID is NOT a unique value, nor is all of the ID's in df1 guaranteed to appear in this df (df2).

```
ID   Category    
001  "Red"
001  "Red"
003  "Blue"
003  "Red"
004  "Red"
```

What I'm trying to do is add a column to the first dataframe that, for example, provides a count of the category with 'Red' if the ID matches the ID in the first dataframe's ID column.  Basically like an index match in excel.

The ID in the second table can appear more than once, but will only appear once in the first table.  The category value can be different in the second table.

I thought I cracked it with the following, but this doesn't work as intended.

```
new_df= pd.crosstab (df2['ID'],df2['CATEGORY'])
```

but this gives me a series with a different length than the initial dataframe (not all ID's in the first dataframe appear in the second)

I also tried the following but again not working as intended.

```
new_df = pd.crosstab(df1['SK_ID_CURR'],df2['NAME_CONTRACT_STATUS'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe need [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), for no matched values get `NaN`s rows:

```
new_df= pd.crosstab (df2['ID'],df2['Category'])
print (new_df)
Category  Blue  Red
ID                 
1            0    2
3            1    1
4            0    1

df = df1.join(new_df, on='ID')
print (df)
   ID   Etc  Etc2  Blue  Red
0   1   foo   bar   0.0  2.0
1   2  foo2  bar2   NaN  NaN
2   3  foo3  bar3   1.0  1.0
```